# How to convert a string variable to System.IO.FileStream object?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am working on VS 2012 Environment using VB.Net (.Net 4.0).

I am reading a .csv file and loading the data to a string variable.  My syntax works fine. I have to do this, just to avoid Carriage Return ( CR ) embedded in the end of line.

Now, I am trying to cast the variable to System.IO.FileStream object.

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\CSV\Test.csv"))
        Dim listA As New List(Of String)()
        Dim listB As New List(Of String)()
        Dim s As String = ""
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim values As String() = line.Split(";"c)
            listA.Add(values(0))
            s = s + line + Chr(10)
        End While
```

I have to pass the System.IO.FileStream object to another existing function which converts to Byte Array.

```
Private Function getEncodeType(ByVal theFile As System.IO.FileStream) As System.Text.Encoding

' This function converts the File Stream to Byte.
' Function works fine.

End Function
```

How to convert the string to System.IO.FileStream object ?

Comment: Don't tag your question C# if it has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the lines in the CSV as a string is immutable. Otherwise if this is VB.Net then you use the `&` rather than a `+` to concatenate the lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conversion.  You create a `FileStream` object and, when you do, you provide a `String` containing the file path.  You're already doing that here:

```
File.OpenRead("D:\CSV\Test.csv")
```

If you want to use that `FileStream` again then, just as with any object or value, you assign it to a variable and then use that variable.